# Why is this make file not working?

Tags: make

I have tried to simplify this makefile to the bare minimum, but cannot get it to use an executable to convert one type of file to another if the timestamps have changed. I'm sure there is a stupidly simple answer but cannot find it:

```
%.pvr : %.bmp
        $(toolpath) -i"$<" -fOGLPVRTC4 -r2 -x512 -y512 -m -o$@

all : 01.pvr

01.pvr : 01.bmp
```

I am attempting to convert all .bmp files specified to .pvr

01.pvr does not exist. 01.bmp does exist. However i always get

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Edit: ok, this was not the exact makefile I was using, in fact the files were not called 01.pvr and 01.bmp, they were foo.pvr and bar.bmp This seems to make a difference. What could that be?

Comment: I just tried your makefile, replacing your `$(toolpath)` command with '`cp $< $@`'. It worked fine. It copied my `01.bmp` to `01.pvr`. You might want to try `make -d` to see whats going on.

Comment: Ah, so my files were actually foo.bmp and bar.pvr does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `%.X : %.Y` kind of rules, `%` acts like a indicator of common substring. Your `makefile` can tell make how to make `foo.pvr` from `foo.bmp`, but not how to make `bar.pvr` from `foo.bmp`. You can find more details in the [Pattern Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html) section of [gmake](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) manual.